# Got solution for building API for search in all categeory

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa

**I m using Spring boot with JPA and created an API which takes 2 parameter category id and product name as follow:**

```
http://localhost:8080/PharmerzWeb/api/v1/products/search/findByCategoryIdAndProductContaining?categoryId=herbal&product=vab_herbal&projection=detail
```

**Now i want to search in all category so and some product id  so how can i modify the same URL to do so.**

**I found the solution for it 
i have to create API which will search with product name only**

```
Page<Product> findByProduct(@Param("productId") String productId, Pageable pageable);
```

And it works just fine

Comment: Did you try to write some code for achieving this?

Comment: No i have used inbuilt jpa functions to achieve this functionality

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do with inbuilt JPA for this.. For your requirement, dont pass the category ID and pass a list of product IDs to the param 'product'. Ideally you will have only one param and that will be the list of product

Comment: i have tried it out but then its giving bad request error. is there any way for this or i need to formulate another API with one parameter i.e. product id.